# How to plot the vertical histogram of an image which contain text - python

Tags: python, opencv, text, histogram, ocr

I want to know how to plot a vertical histogram of an image in opencv using python in order to identify the text lines of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MJRS.jpg)

[image]

Comment: What is your _question_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add up the elements of each row and plot a histogram to find out the row's number.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", 0)
img = 255-img

img_row_sum = np.sum(img,axis=1).tolist()

plt.plot(img_row_sum)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The height signifies the amount of text in the line and the x axis shows the row numbers with text. You can properly threshold both of these to get the rows with written text.